# How to jump to a C/C++ function declaration instead of its definition?

Tags: c++, c, vim, editor

I know CTRL+] to jump to definition of a function in various languages in vim.
What about jump to declaration in C/C++ header?

Since I have plenty of headers containing meaningful comments/explanations, I would frequently find function declarations among a large code base. Is there some sorts of shortcuts to do this?

Comment: Well, That's not a feature of `vim` actually. They are `ctags`.

Comment: In `ctags` there no such support. But there is a similar feature `cscope` and grep plugin support in vim.

Answer (score 10):

ctags does not add function prototypes by default. You have to add the option

> --c++-kinds=+p

to support function prototypes.
My ctags looks like this:

> ctags --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS --extra=+q *.h *.c

When you are at a tag, you can use the following editor commands to browser through the tags (Meaning the same tag occuring multiple times as definition/declaration)-

> tn (Next Tag)
>
> tp (Previous Tag)

Comment: when I use CTRL+], it still goes to function definition

Comment: Pressing `2CTRL+]` should do it. Your tags file holds now both the function declaration and the definition. `CTRL+]` jumps to the first matching entry in the tags file. To go to the second, press `2CTRL+]`, etc. I'm not quite sure how ctags sorts them, first declaration then definition or vice versa (maybe sort order is what ctags finds first).

Comment: Actually your command simply doesn't work. It gives the following: '''ctags: Warning: cannot open source file "*.h" : No such file or directory
ctags: Warning: cannot open source file "*.c" : No such file or directory'''. I tried ctags --fields=+iaS --extra=+q -R and work on a particular function. Now 2CTRL+] goes to another definition (static inline function surrounded by macros with identical name in a header), and with 3CTRL-] I finally reach my declaration

Answer (score 2):

Based on [Bram's 7 habits](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiKmfz_xPDVAhXEpo8KHS01D8sQFggnMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.moolenaar.net%2Fhabits_2007.pdf&usg=AFQjCNFbCNQcMbS849ckrsaPjbef8hKZsw), without any plugin, you can do

1) Set the path to your headers(This is crucial to work with point 2 below)

```
:set path+=/path/to/headers
```

2) Then do one of the following command

`[I` Display all list where keyword under cursor is in header files or

`[<Tab>` will jump there and you can come back to your file using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

I am satisfied with cscope, which includes header files in database.

Just put [cscope_maps.vim](http://cscope.sourceforge.net/cscope_maps.vim) in ~/.vim/plugin/ and then CTRL-] will list all choices if a cscope database is built.

To build a cscope database, just type

```
cscope -bR
```